# Is the DOM stored in ram normally or in heap memory?

Tags: javascript

I'm confused about the JavaScript data structure. I know that JavaScript uses the stack and heap memory data structure, but I don't understand why a very large DOM causes crashes, but if I just add a large video on the page, for example, the DOM is still light. Videos and audios are outside the stack and heap memory? if the question is confusing, I'm sorry, but I don't understand how I can load a 2GB video on a page, for example, and not run out of limited JavaScript memory, but if the DOM nodes are about 10MB, for example, the page it starts to lose performance.

Comment: Stack and heap are both in RAM. Videos are not completely loaded; only a portion around the current viewing location in the stream.

Comment: But when the video is fully loaded, is it on the heap?

Comment: @Boruto Pretty much *everything* that is not a local variable in a currently executing function is on the heap. But no, a video most likely is not on the JavaScript heap, since it's not a Javascript object, it's allocated somewhere on the heap that the browser engine uses for its native objects (just like most parts of the DOM are).

Comment: I'm no expert on Internet video but I have my doubts that any browser stores the *entirety* of an hour-long YouTube video.

Comment: @Pointy agreed - and even if it does, it would most likely be either in the http cache (on disk) or in the virtual memory swap file (on disk), not in physical ram.

Answer (score 1):

Both are stored in RAM. And both are stored in the Heap.

However, DOMs are more complicated than a simple image.

[image]

Here the DOM is represented as a tree, both abstractly, and in RAM. So, if the DOM gets too big, you lose performance drastically as it gets increasingly more expensive to get from root node to leaf node in this tree.

This is amplified dramatically by CSS and formatting rules. Since if a node at the top changes position, it could invalidate the entire tree with respect to CSS positioning. Additionally, if the node at the leaf changes position, it could still cause repositions to cascade up the tree.

In both directions, a large DOM tree can cause performance to come to a grinding halt.

Comment: I may have misunderstood, but is the DOM heavier by the number of nodes and not necessarily by the size of the files loaded on the page?

Comment: @Boruto When the DOM is bigger, it's slower to traverse it, and slower to parse and render it. This causes performance to drop. It doesn't have to do with RAM or out-of-memory issues.